# Facing syntax error while running source venv.source on mac terminal

Tags: python, cheetah

I am running "source venv.source" command in my Mac terminal inside a cloned repo from Github, can someone please help me.

```
=========================================
Activating virtual environment
=========================================
Executing: source /Users/jillasai.krishna/test_data_venv/bin/activate
Done

=========================================
Installing requirements inside virtual environment
=========================================
Executing: pip install -r /Users/jillasai.krishna/pi-tcms-1/pi-tcms/requirements.txt
Collecting cheetah==2.4.4
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/b0/c2d700252fc251e91c08639ff41a8a5203b627f4e0a2ae18a6b662ab32ea/Cheetah-2.4.4.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/jillasai.krishna/test_data_venv/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4b/6t4qhtp51zlg9dqbh8hv743c0000gp/T/pip-install-y1gjebi8/cheetah/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4b/6t4qhtp51zlg9dqbh8hv743c0000gp/T/pip-install-y1gjebi8/cheetah/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/4b/6t4qhtp51zlg9dqbh8hv743c0000gp/T/pip-install-y1gjebi8/cheetah/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/4b/6t4qhtp51zlg9dqbh8hv743c0000gp/T/pip-install-y1gjebi8/cheetah/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/4b/6t4qhtp51zlg9dqbh8hv743c0000gp/T/pip-install-y1gjebi8/cheetah/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        import SetupTools
      File "/private/var/folders/4b/6t4qhtp51zlg9dqbh8hv743c0000gp/T/pip-install-y1gjebi8/cheetah/SetupTools.py", line 50
        except DistutilsPlatformError, x:
                                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Done

Could not install all the requirements
```

Expecting to setup venv successfully but running into the above Error.

Comment: It looks like you have a python version different than the venv.

Comment: ```C02S86LUFVH7-blr:pi-tcms jillasai.krishna$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.```
this is my python version

Comment: @loki please help me how can I get to know venv version?

Comment: Did you create the venv separately from the cloned repo?

Comment: I have cloned a repo from GitHub and ran source venv.source command in that repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `/Users/jillasai.krishna/pi-tcms-1/pi-tcms/requirements.txt` contains `cheetah==2.4.4`. This version of Cheetah is only for Python2 and you're trying to use with Python3.

Either use your project with Python 2.7 or upgrade the project to Python 3. [Cheetah3](https://pypi.org/project/Cheetah3/) supports both Python 2.7 and 3.4+.

First thing to try is to replace `cheetah==2.4.4` with `Cheetah3==3.2.4`.

Comment: Installing requirements inside virtual environment
=========================
Executing: pip install -r /Users/jillasai.krishna/pi-tcms-1/pi-tcms/requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cheetah==3.2.4 (from -r /Users/jillasai.krishna/pi-tcms-1/pi-tcms/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 1.0, 2.0rc7, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.2.1, 2.4.3, 2.4.4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cheetah==3.2.4 (from -r /Users/jillasai.krishna/pi-tcms-1/pi-tcms/requirements.txt (line 1))
Done
Could not install all the requirements

Comment: I am not sure how to upgrade the project to Python 3, I replaced cheetah==2.4.4 with Cheetah3==3.2.4 and facing the above error now.

Comment: **Cheetah3==3.2.4**, not *cheetah==3.2.4*.